# How to catch exception from processpool executer in python3

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing

How can i catch exception from a processpool executer? i have used result() but it slows down the proccess i think is there any other method?

```
   with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(50) as genrator:
                    try:

                    for fl in self.finallist:

                        print("FIKLENAME",fl)

                        futures=[genrator.submit(insta.load_instantel_ascii, fl,None,',')]
                        results = [f.result() for f in futures]

                except Exception as e:

                    print("EXCE", e)
                    print("FILENAME IS",fl)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `concurrent.futures.as_completed` to get an iterator that yields futures as they complete. There should be minimal gains here should you use this API.

Also build an iterable of futures to be used outside of the *for loop*.

```
def submit_task(executor, args):
    print('FILENAME', args[1])
    executor.submit(*args)

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(50) as executor:
    try:
        futures = [
            submit_task(executor, (insta.load_instantel_ascii, fl, None, ',')) 
            for fl in self.finallist
        ]
        futures_as_completed = concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures)
        results = [future.result() for future in futures_as_completed]
    except Exception as exc:
        print("EXCEPTION: ", exc)
```

**EDIT**

To get `fl` inside of the exception block e.g. `print('EXCEPTION: ', exc.fl)`, you can either catch the exception in the caller and re-raise it with a name binding to `fl` or implement a custom exception with an attribute binding to `fl` that is raised in the caller.

For the former, decorate `insta.load_instantel_ascii` **if you don't have access to modify it**.

```
def try_except_fl(method, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        return method(*args, **kwargs)
    except Exception as exc:
        fl = args[0]
        exc.fl = fl
        raise exc
```

**If you have access to modify `insta.load_instantel_ascii`**, wrap the procedure in a `try/except`.

```
def load_instantel_ascii(self, fl, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        # do some compute intensive tasks here
    except Exception as exc:
        exc.fl = fl
        raise exc
```

For the later, raise a custom exception with an attribute bound to `fl`. *e.g.*

```
class ProcessFailure(Exception):  # you may want to subclass a specialized exception class.
    message = 'Alas! This task had a lot of errors.'

    def __init__(fl):
        self.fl = fl
```

Raise this in failure point.*i.e.* `load_instantel_ascii`.

```
def load_instantel_ascii(self, fl, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        # do some compute intensive tasks here
    except Exception as exc:
        raise ProcessFailure(fl)
```

Comment: Let me give it a try

Comment: how do i get the fl varible into exeption block?

Comment: you can raise a custom exception and have it passed as an attribute of a raised instance of your custom exception.

Comment: Ok let me give it a try

Comment: @chris1234 See __EDIT__

Comment: Let me give it a try